# Writing XML string in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to construct an XML string to pass as the body of an HTTP request but I'm getting a bit stuck. Here's the function that should build the string:

```
    public function build_calendarquery()
{

    $body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
                    <C:'.$this->report_type.' xmlns:D="DAV:"
                    xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
                    <D:prop>
                        <D:getetag/>
                        <C:calendar-data>
                        <C:comp name="VCALENDAR">
                        <C:prop name="VERSION"/>
                        <C:comp name="VEVENT">'; 

        foreach($this->cal_props as $prop)
        {
            $body .= '<C:prop name="'.strtoupper($prop).'" />';                                                                
        }

        $body .= '</C:comp>';

        $body .= '<C:comp name="VTIMEZONE" />
                    </C:comp>
                        </C:calendar-data>
                        </D:prop>';

        if($this->filters){

            $body .= '<C:filter>
                        <C:comp-filter name="VCALENDAR">
                            <C:comp-filter name="VEVENT">';

            foreach($this->filters as $filter=>$val) 
            {
                $body .= '<C:'.$filter.' '.$val.'/>';
            }

            $body .= '</C:comp-filter>
                        </C:comp-filter>
                            </C:filter>';
        }

        $body .= '</C:calendar-query>'; 

        return $body;
}
```

The problem I have is that when I try and use the data returned from this function there doesn't seem to be anything there. What I mean is, if I write:

```
var_dump($this->build_calendarquery());
```

It returns NULL.

I've never really worked with XML before. Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: I don't see how this method can return `null` as there is at least `'</C:calendar-query>'` in `$body` right before you `return $body;`. do you get any kind of error or exception, that you are catching? what's inside `$this->report_type`?

Comment: You are not by any chance calling `var_dump($this->[..]);` outside of your objects methods, are you? `$this` is only valid inside object's methods.

Comment: I know that I'm building the string ok cos I can send it to the browser and read it before I return it as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tested your code locally and there is nothing wrong with the part you have provided.

```
<?php
class Test
{
    public $report_type="foo";
    public $cal_props = array();
    public $filters = array();
    public function build_calendarquery()
    {

        $body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
                        <C:'.$this->report_type.' xmlns:D="DAV:"
                        xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
                        <D:prop>
                            <D:getetag/>
                            <C:calendar-data>
                            <C:comp name="VCALENDAR">
                            <C:prop name="VERSION"/>
                            <C:comp name="VEVENT">'; 

            foreach($this->cal_props as $prop)
            {
                $body .= '<C:prop name="'.strtoupper($prop).'" />';                                                                
            }

            $body .= '</C:comp>';

            $body .= '<C:comp name="VTIMEZONE" />
                        </C:comp>
                            </C:calendar-data>
                            </D:prop>';

            if($this->filters){

                $body .= '<C:filter>
                            <C:comp-filter name="VCALENDAR">
                                <C:comp-filter name="VEVENT">';

                foreach($this->filters as $filter=>$val) 
                {
                    $body .= '<C:'.$filter.' '.$val.'/>';
                }

                $body .= '</C:comp-filter>
                            </C:comp-filter>
                                </C:filter>';
            }

            $body .= '</C:calendar-query>'; 

            return $body;
    }
    public function doVarDump()
    {
        var_dump($this->build_calendarquery());
    }
}

$test = new Test();
var_dump($test->build_calendarquery());
$test->doVarDump();
?>
```

outputs:

```
string '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
                        <C:foo xmlns:D="DAV:"
                        xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
                        <D:prop>
                            <D:getetag/>
                            <C:calendar-data>
                            <C:comp name="VCALENDAR">
                            <C:prop name="VERSION"/>
                            <C:comp name="VEVENT"></C:comp><C:comp name="VTIMEZONE" />
                        </C:comp>
                            </C:calendar-data>
                            </D:prop></C:calendar-query>' (length=383)
string '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
                        <C:foo xmlns:D="DAV:"
                        xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
                        <D:prop>
                            <D:getetag/>
                            <C:calendar-data>
                            <C:comp name="VCALENDAR">
                            <C:prop name="VERSION"/>
                            <C:comp name="VEVENT"></C:comp><C:comp name="VTIMEZONE" />
                        </C:comp>
                            </C:calendar-data>
                            </D:prop></C:calendar-query>' (length=383)
```

You will need to show us some more code. I'm interested as to where your `var_dump($this->build_calendarquery());` statement is located.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help but I've realised I was just being stupid and not properly passing the string along the method trace properly. All fixed now. Should I delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

Use class or try to remove the declaration of function to public and check all variable like ($this->report_type,$this->cal_props...etc) ...etc

i have doubt for $this->cal_props

i try your code as below
NOTE :- Remove all your $this variable

```
function build_calendarquery()
```

{

```
$body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
                <C: xmlns:D="DAV:"
                xmlns:C="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:caldav">
                <D:prop>
                    <D:getetag/>
                    <C:calendar-data>
                    <C:comp name="VCALENDAR">
                    <C:prop name="VERSION"/>
                    <C:comp name="VEVENT">'; 



    $body .= '</C:comp>';

    $body .= '<C:comp name="VTIMEZONE" />
                </C:comp>
                    </C:calendar-data>
                    </D:prop>';



        $body .= '<C:filter>
                    <C:comp-filter name="VCALENDAR">
                        <C:comp-filter name="VEVENT">';



        $body .= '</C:comp-filter>
                    </C:comp-filter>
                        </C:filter>';


    $body .= '</C:calendar-query>'; 

    return $body;
```

}
var_dump(build_calendarquery());
Output is string(792) " "

Answer (score -2):

var_dump won't work on functions. Try storing the result of the function in a variable and then var_dump it:

```
$result = $this->build_calendarquery();
var_dump($result);
```

Also, I don't know if PHP likes it when you span your single-quoted strings over multiple lines...

Comment: Spanning the single-quoted text over multiple lines is fine.

Comment: Thanks for this. I didn't realise that about var_dump. I do store things in variables first anyway - I was just saving typing of the question! As far as I know, PHP ignores white space so that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: don't listen to him. you can `var_dump` anything you want.